# Combining background for menu and dropdown

Tags: html, css, menu

I just want to create a menu with drop down.. my question is I just want to merge background of main menu and the dropdown as the below image.. Please help me out..

image of the menu

```
http://s1369.photobucket.com/user/ashast1/media/Capture_zps0b0c58e6.png.html
```

jsfiddle for the menu

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/6KPXC/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/dv9GS/)**</kbd>

```
.nav ul{list-style-type:none; position:relative;}
.nav ul li{position:relative; text-transform:uppercase; display:inline-block;}
.nav ul li:hover a{border:1px solid #d7d7d7;background:#fff;color:#f9852b; border-bottom:none;}
.nav ul li a{position: relative; padding:10px; color:#5E6062; display:block;border:1px solid #fff; z-index: 100;}
.nav ul li a:hover{position: relative; color:#f9852b;border:1px solid #d7d7d7; z-index:11; border-bottom:none;}
.nav ul li:hover ul{display:block;padding:20px;}
.nav ul ul{position:absolute; display:none; min-width: 200px; border:1px solid #d7d7d7; border-top: none; margin-top:-1px;left:-10px;z-index:10;}
.nav ul ul:after{position: absolute; content: ""; top: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; border-top:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
.nav ul ul li a, .nav li:hover li a{border:0px; color:#515151; text-transform:capitalize;padding:3px 10px;}
.nav ul ul li a:hover, .nav li:hover li a:hover{border:none; color:#515151; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: great.. it is working fine.. One thing.. You've defined width for this menu.. so I've to define different width for different menu items..

isn't a way to generalize this..?